# Device can speak to LAN one way, and can get on WAN/Internet

Tags: networking, windows-10

I have a device on my network (I have tried disabling the firewall, turned off the local security settings in the router - everything I can think of) and it just refuses to speak.

No idea what to do!

1 - Router TL-WR841N - 192.168.0.1

2 - Desktop - 192.168.0.2 - The annoying one

3 - Laptop - 192.168.0.3

4 - Phone - 192.168.0.4

---

At first I thought it was the laptop and desktop refusing to speak to each-other.

But then I found out that desktop can communicate with all other devices fine (one way, from Desktop to the other devices) - but I have tried pinging the desktop, and tried accessing the VMware panel from my laptop, but no success.

---

So then:

- The desktop CAN connect to the internet.
- The desktop can communicate outwards to all other devices
- No devices can communicate inwards to the desktop
- Every now and then the desktop is unable to talk to other LAN devices
  (but it doesn't last long)
- I have ran Malwarebytes and Avast
- It is not the firewall
- I have tried testing the device on another network to see if it's a problem with the router, and in the end is was not. It's definitely a problem with the desktop

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hm.. I first thought you have "AP isolation" enabled on your router, but you claim desktop->other devices works. Do you have a reasonable test e.g. for laptop -> desktop? It requires some network service running, not hindered by the machine's firewall.

Comment: I've been trying to communicate from Phone/Laptop -> Desktop by attempting to connect on VMWare horizion, VMWare workstation, pinging it, and heading to its IP looking for a `Unauthorised` response, but I just get `Your request timed out`

Comment: Is that a good test? I you want to reach a service running within the VMware, this is more complicated (bridging, natd and so on) than having some other service, like a http server, directly running on the machine. It could be as simple as `ruby -run -e httpd -- -p 5000 .` or `python3 -m http.server 8082` .

Comment: I'm not speaking about VMWare, I just meant I used that to test if I could connect or not. I'll start a http server now to test. But when I went ahead and put the IP in my browser I didn't get the denied response, I just got a time-out.

Comment: Still no response with the http server running

Comment: It's on all network interface (wifi, Ethernet, virtual Ethernet adapter for our VPN), it does take a dhcp reservation, it acts like the device doesn't exist after that reservation, BUT I was able to find the device on an nmap scan?

Comment: Nmap scan report for 192.168.x.x

Host is up (0.098s latency).

MAC Address: xx (xx)

Comment: Maybe a network tool like MessageAnalyzer (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226) can give you more insight.

Comment: Forgot message analyser existed

Comment: Wasn't able to get anything useful out of message analyser, but it applies to ALL network interfaces.

Comment: What I don't get it a ping is a 2 way process. You send the packet, you get a reply. So my desktop sends a packet to my laptop, it receives it, then IT CAN REPLY. But when I try sending a packet from any device to the desktop: nothing happens. No reply, a time-out; like if it didn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve the issue, as I said it was a software issue.

Sadly it was a problem with avast, after repairing it - it now works fine. This was as avast kept freezing up and crashing (and its never happened before). I would like to thank mvw for his help as well!

Comment: Glad you got it working.

Comment: Thanks for your help, in the end it was avast. It kept freezing up then randomly changed all networks to public networks and got really defensive.

Comment: Never had an issue with avast in the years I've used it. Going to use glasswire for my firewall from now on (I bought a key for it a while ago but didn't really use it) So I might as well use my key and glasswire has more features for a firewall, including traffic monitoring!

Comment: Another lesson to keep an interfering anti malware on the list of culprits. They seem to dig deep into the operating system.